# Responsive brand image on navbar

Tags: html, css, image, twitter-bootstrap

I got a problem in image on navbar when i tried to minimize it as smaller i can the image is being pushed down by the collapse button. Is it possible to make the image become responsive without using media queries? Because i think it's a bad practice as a beginner to use media queries just to make image become responsive and i think there are other ways to make this possible without using media queries :) Im new to html, css, and also to bootstrap. Thanks in advance.

Here is the image when not minimized.[image]

Here is the image when minimized as you can see the picture is being pushed down by the collapse button.
[image]

here is my html code for navbar.

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="nav-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#">Students</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Faculty</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>

    </ul>

    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
                <!-- Modal -->
                    <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
                        <div class="modal-dialog">
                <!-- Modal content--> 
                         <div class="modal-content">
                             <div class="modal-header"> 
                                 <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                             </div>
                             <div class="modal-body">
                                <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
                             </div>
                             <div class="modal-footer">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                             </div>
                         </div>
                        </div>
                   </div>
         </ul>
      </div>
     </div>
   </nav>
```

here is my css

```
 .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
 font-weight: 590;
 color: #949494;
 display: block;
 padding: 5px 35px 2px 45px;
 border-bottom: 3px solid transparent;
 line-height: 97px;
 text-decoration: none;
 transition: border-bottom-color 0.5s ease-in-out;
 -webkit-transition: border-bottom-color 0.5s ease-in-out; 
 }
 .navbar-default{
 background-color:#fff;
 margin: 0;

 }
 .nav>li>a {
 position: relative;
 }
.navbar-default .navbar-right > li > a {
 padding-left: 70px;
 padding-right: 1px;
 }
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
 background-color: #000000;
 margin:0 0 4px;
 width: 25px;
 height: 5px;

}
 .nav.navbar-nav > li{
 display: :inline-block;
 }
 .nav.navbar-nav{
 list-style-type:none;
 }
 .nav.navbar-nav > li > a:hover{
    color:#a92419;
   border-bottom-color: #a92419;
  }

      .navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
       background-color:#a92419 ;
       margin:0 0 4px;
        width: 25px;
       height: 5px;

       }
       .navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus, .navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover{
        background: none;
        }
        button.navbar-toggle{
        background:none;
        border:none;
        color:#000;
        }
```

Comment: Where is the code for the image?

Comment: There is no css for image sir. I don't know what to put.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap your image in an anchor tag and give it a class of navbar-brand and give the image an id.

```
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img id="logo" src="logo.png"></a>
```

The navbar-brand class will help give it that responsiveness and you can use the id #logo to control the images size and placement alternatively you can specify the width and height of the image as attributes like:

```
 <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img id="logo" src="logo.png" height="42" width="42"></a>
```

Just change the numbers to your desired size . Check out this link to bootstrap the talks about using the navbar-brand class for images. http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-brand-image

Comment: My image is so big as you can see

Comment: You need to specify what size you want your image to be. use  #logo{ width: 50px; height: 50px;}      50px; is just an example you would need to use a height and width that will work best for you. if you use px you will need to add the proper media queries to make it responsive. Alternatively you can declare percentages instead of px. if you use percentages you will not need the media queries.